# How to use one entity class with multiple databases by @Autowire and @Qualifier

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I use the project of https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-boot-transaction.
And I changed the application.properties to:

```
datasource.admin.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/multidbadmin
datasource.admin.username=multidbuser
datasource.admin.password=multidbuser

datasource.local.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/multidblocal
datasource.local.username=multidbuser
datasource.local.password=multidbuser

spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
```

In the project is the customer entity assigned to the AdminConfiguration and the product entity is assigned to the LocalConfiguration.

Now, I would like to use both entities in each Configuration. So I would like to work with @Qualifier by autowiring to differentiate the datatsource/transaction.

Therefore I changed the "basePackages" -path for the repositories to "org.example.data" to get each JPARepository in both TransactionManagers and the packages -path for the entities to "org.example.domain" to enable working with each entity (developed once - Because I want not to write the customer entity twice, one in the package A and the other in package B).

And then I would like to have something like:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("adminRepository")
private CustomerRepository adminRepository;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userRepository")
private CustomerRepository userRepository;
```

How can I solve this?